# Selectively delete rows in a csv file (Python)

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I am reading in a `.csv` file of space-delimited data, which contains some unwanted words. I need to find if unwanted words are present in *any* of columns of a given row, and delete that row.

For example, if `unwanted_list = ['one', 'on']`, then for an input `.csv` file with columns *name class label test*;

Input:

```
ne two 1 five,
on one 2 we.
as we 20 on
cast as none vote
```

Representative output:

```
ne two 1 five,
cast as none vote
```

Comment: Why isn't `ne two 1 five,` in your example output? Given that it contains neither `'one'` or `'on'`?

Comment: yup tom..it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple script using the python `set` object should do the trick. This checks that there are no words common to both the set of unwanted words, and the set of words in the line of the input file;

```
def filter_unwanted_words():
    unwanted_words = {'one', 'on'}
    with open('input.csv', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if set(line.split()).isdisjoint(unwanted_words):
                yield line


def write_output():
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines((line for line in filter_unwanted_words()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_output()
```

The output in `output.csv` for this is;

```
ne two 1 five,
cast as none vote
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have a look at the csv module documentation, https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Here is an example code in ipython.

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: f = open('plop.csv')

In [3]: exclude = set(('on', 'one'))

In [4]: reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')

In [5]: for row in reader:
   ...:     if any(val in exclude for val in row):
   ...:         continue
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print row
   ...:         
['name', 'class', 'label', 'test']
['ne', 'two', '1', 'five,']
['cast', 'as', 'none', 'vote']
```

Feel free to adapt the script to your needs.

Take care that i did not provide special processinng for the header which can be handled this way. This is not how you should process for very large files since the whole file is read an put into ram.

```
In [9]: f=open('plop.csv')

In [10]: reader = csv.reader(f.readlines()[1:], delimiter=' ') #skip headers

In [11]: for row in reader:
    ...:     if any(val in exclude for val in row):
    ...:         continue
    ...:     else:
    ...:         print row
    ...:         
['ne', 'two', '1', 'five,']
['cast', 'as', 'none', 'vote']
```